# ASP.NET MVC inline bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, optimization

I'm using ASP.NET MVC bundles to organise and optimise my scripts and CSS.  The site I'm currently developing needs to perform well on mobile networks, so I'm trying to get all my html, JavaScript and CSS into a single request.  Is there any way to get an MVC bundle to inline its contents in the requested html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, there is.** I've blogged about how to inline script and style bundles because I was facing the exact same problem. Here's the post:

- [Inlining CSS and JavaScript Bundles with ASP.NET MVC](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/10/25/inlining-css-and-javascript-bundles-with-asp-net-mvc)

The basic idea is to grab the `BundleResponse` that's created by the *System.Web.Optimization* framework and emit its contents within a `<style>` or `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to do this.

From yslow best practices

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external

Using external files in the real world generally produces faster pages because the JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser. JavaScript and CSS that are inlined in HTML documents get downloaded every time the HTML document is requested. This reduces the number of HTTP requests that are needed, but increases the size of the HTML document. On the other hand, if the JavaScript and CSS are in external files cached by the browser, the size of the HTML document is reduced without increasing the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand all the above.  What I'm trying to achieve is a site that shows a rendered page in under a second in the uncached state over a crummy 3G network.  It's not uncommon to have latencies of 600ms or more so a second request that gets issued to retrieve further resources vital to the initial display of the page isn't an option.

Comment: How many pages do you have in your site? If you inline all your javascript and css it wont get cached for subsequent requests. So while doing it your way the first request might be quicker, all subsequent requests for other pages would be slower as you have to reload all the js and css with every single page. Unless there is only 1 page on your site of course.

Comment: Many pages.  Although there are two that will definitely get visited most often.  I'm working on the rule of thumb that 20% of page requests will be from users with nothing in the cache.  I'd like to put the CSS and JavaScript for initial page display inline and then load in further resources later.  I am happy for subsequent pages to take a bit longer to render as long as all requests render in less than a second.